# Exception calling ".ctor" with 5 arguments among other errors

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a script to automate a process and i'm running into issues setting permissions on a network share. Please have a look at the code below.

```
$Employee = Get-ADUser -Identity test_Person  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

$Manager = Get-ADUser -Identity test_Person  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Manager

$Drive = "\\Sharename\directory\"

$ACL = Get-Acl "$Drive\$($Employee)"

$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Manager, "FullControl", "containerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")

$ACL.SetAccessRule($Ar)

Set-Acl "$Drive\$($Employee)" $ACL
```

**Here are the errors. Any help is greatly appreciated**

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "5" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: identity"
>   At line:5 char:7
>   + $Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($ ...
>   +       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
>
> Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: rule"
>   At line:6 char:1
>   + $ACL.SetAccessRule($Ar)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException
>
> Set-Acl : The process does not possess the 'SeSecurityPrivilege' privilege which is required for this operation.
>   At line:7 char:1
>   + Set-Acl "$LDrive\$($Employee)" $ACL
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\Drive\Directory\Test_Person:String) [Set-Acl], PrivilegeNotHeldException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.AccessControl.PrivilegeNotHeldException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand

Comment: This may not be the entirety of your issues, but `$Manager` is empty because `Get-ADUser` does not return the Manager property by default. You have to include it with `-Property Manager`. Second, the manager property returns the DN of the manager object. I do not know if `FileSystemAccessRule()` accepts a DN or if it needs to be the SamAccountName or SID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change how you are handling the returned manager data. You must look up the `SamAccountName` or `SecurityIdentitifer` value for the manager object before passing it into `FileSystemAccessRule()`.

```
$Employee = Get-ADUser -Identity test_Person -Properties Manager
$Manager = Get-ADUser -Identity $Employee.Manager | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
$Drive = "\\Sharename\directory"
$ACL = Get-Acl "$Drive\$($Employee.SamAccountName)"

$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Manager, "FullControl", "containerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$ACL.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl "$Drive\$($Employee.SamAccountName)" $ACL
```

In your attempt, `$Manager` is empty because `Get-ADUser` does not return the Manager property by default. You have to include it with `-Property Manager`. Second, the manager property returns the DN of the manager object. `FileSystemAccessRule()` accepts an `IdentityReference` object derived from `SamAccountName` or `SID`, which means you must perform a conversion or another lookup for the proper data format.